# How do I create a query to arrange my data in a certain format?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my class:

```
public class Students
{
    public String StudentName
    public int CountActivities
    public List<Activities> lstActivities = new List<Activities>();
}    
public class Activities
{
    public String ActivityName
    public int ActivityScore
}
```

I'd like to create a query that shows the students Name as Rows, and the ActivityName as Columns in a datagrid.  If an activity was done by a student, show the score in the appropriate row & cell.  We know that the List of Activities can vary from 1 to X in count, but never exceed X.  I'd like CountActivities to be the 2nd column next to the students' Names.  The 3rd column onwards are labeled by the various ActivityName that students participate in.

How do I create a query to display what I want in a datagrid?  I know I have to create a query that results in a List.  Then I can set the datagrid's source to the List (I think).  My trouble is understanding how to formulate a query to present the information in the format I just described.

Sorry, I didn't add this part earlier:

```
List<Students> lstHighSchool = new List<Students>();
var Query = lstHighSchool ( *no clue*).ToList():
//from here I can hopefully assign List to datagrid's source.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your **question** was **challenging**, so I have been playing around trying to get there.  Not sure if it is what you want, it needs cleaning up a bit to make it more generic.

My idea was to build a linq extension to provide the structure you requested.  I am moving the data into a Tuple where Item1 is a string containing the StudentName and Item2 is a List of ActivityScores having enough rows for all distinct activity names.  The scores are added correctly to a col that matches the sorted distinct list I create from the Student List so that you get a correct col for every activity score.

I then print out the results to the Debug Window.  The results are correct for my sample, but there may be some bugs.  It is a start anyway :)

```
Another path could be just to build a List<string[]> in place of the
Tuple<string, List<int>>, and everything is converted to string for display.
```

Any Suggestions are welcome.

**Here it is:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;


    namespace SO
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Create Students List
                var students = new List<Student>()
                {
                    new Student
                    {
                        FirstName = "Paul",
                        LastName = "Smith",
                        ActivityList = new List<Activity>() { 
                            new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Math", ActivityScore = 90                        
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Biology", ActivityScore = 92                        
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "C#", ActivityScore = 93                        
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Student
                    {
                        FirstName = "Mary",
                        LastName = "Jones",
                        ActivityList = new List<Activity>() { 
                            new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Linq", ActivityScore = 95                       
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Phyics", ActivityScore = 99                        
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "C#", ActivityScore = 99                        
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Student
                    {
                        FirstName = "Slick",
                        LastName = "Willy",
                        ActivityList = new List<Activity>() { 
                            new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Wine", ActivityScore = 90                        
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Women", ActivityScore = 99                        
                            },
                           new Activity
                            {
                                ActivityName = "Politics", ActivityScore = 85                        
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };



                // Created a sorted list of activity Names
                var activities = (from s in students from a in s.ActivityList select (a.ActivityName)).Distinct().ToList();
                activities.Sort();

                // Create a Tuple of <Name,Activities>
                var grid = students.DataGrid(activities);


                // Print Header
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("{0,-12}", "Name"));
                foreach (var item in activities)
                {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("{0,12}",item));
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

                // Print Rows
                foreach (var t in grid)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("{0,-12}", t.Item1));
                    foreach (var s in t.Item2)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("{0,12}", s));
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                }

                // Done
            }
        }



    public class Student
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Activity> ActivityList { get; set; }
    }    

    public class Activity
    {
        public String ActivityName { get; set; }
        public int ActivityScore { get; set; }
    }


    public static class LinqExt2
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>> DataGrid<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> columnList)
        {


            using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                // A List of Tuples in the format <string, List<int>>
                var results = new List<Tuple<string, List<int>>>();

                // each Student
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var a = iterator.Current as Student;
                    if (a == null)
                        continue;

                    // initalize all cols to 0;
                    var columnValues = columnList.Select(v => 0).ToList();

                    // each Activity
                    foreach (var item in a.ActivityList)
                    {
                        var name = item.ActivityName;
                        var i = 0;
                        foreach (var activity in columnList)
                        {
                            if (name.Equals(activity))
                            {
                                columnValues[i] = item.ActivityScore;
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    results.Add(Tuple.Create(a.FirstName, columnValues));
                }

                return results;
            }
        }
    }




    }
```

**Results**

Name             Biology          C#        Linq        Math      Phyics    Politics        Wine       Women
Paul                  92          93           0          90           0           0           0           0
Mary                   0          99          95           0          99           0           0           0
Slick                  0           0           0           0           0          85          90          99

Answer (score 1):

That will be difficult (and static) in Linq - I would instead create a DataTable that loops through the activities, creating columns if they don't exist.

pseudo-code:

```
DataTable dt
add column Name
add column CountActivities
foreach(student)
{
    add row
    row[Name] = student.Name
    row[CountActivities] = student.CountActivities
    foreach(activity)
    {
        if(! (dt contains column (activity.ActivityName)))
            add column (activity.ActivityName)
        row[activity.ActivityName] = ActivityScore
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do everything up until this line: if(! (dt contains column (activity.ActivityName)))...How do I check if the Datable contains a column by the name of activityname?

Comment: Use [`DataColumnCollection.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx) : `if(!dt.Columns.Contains(activity.ActivityName))`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called a "Pivot Table".

It is not feasible in LINQ. See ([How to build pivot table through linq using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495124/how-to-build-pivot-table-through-linq-using-c-sharp))

See another option here: [Pivot logic LINQ on DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211283/pivot-logic-linq-on-datatable?rq=1)